# Xero API: How to access all tenants connected to app

Tags: xero-api

I have a created a Xero web app. We have added this to Codat as an accounting integration (https://docs.codat.io/docs/accounting-xero-setup).

Other Xero users have created organisations and are able to use this integration. Unfortunately, Codat doesn't meet all our requirements, so we will be needing to access Xero organisations via Xero APIs.

I've started by looking at this example https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-netstandard-oauth2-app. I can see that if I use my Xero user credentials (which are different to my xero-developer credentials), I can choose any of my own tenants.

Is there a way of using my xero-developer credentials to access *all* the tenants using my app, and not just those of one user?  Using Codat, I can access all tenants, which suggests it can be done.

N.B. all our Xero organisations are trial ones - not sure if that affects matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe what you are looking for is possible.

The way we do this in Codat is to go through our "link" journey (the process of connecting a tenant to our service) once per tenant and we store the tokens separately for each tenant.